# Young's Inequality in Locally Convex Spaces

Tags: young-inequality

I'm trying to understand a proof of a Lemma that's in relation to Young's inequality, the lemma is the following : Suppose $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$

Let $a,b>0$ and let $1<p<\infty$ such that $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$. Then
$$ab = \min_{1<t<\infty} \frac{t^pa^p}{p} + \frac{t^{-q}b^q}{q}$$

It says this can be proved by "the methods of elementary calculus," but I don't see how this is the case. If you differentiate with respect to t the function that is being minimised you get $t^{p-1}a^p - t^{-q-1}b^q = 0$. But I don't understand how you get the proof from this.

Comment: What is $a\cdots b$ ?

Comment: It's meant to be ab @Hamdiken

Comment: Just write $ab$ as $(at)(\frac b t)$ and apply Young's inequality.

Comment: @geetha290krm then where does the minimum part come in?

Comment: You get LHS $\leq$ RHS. Find where  the minimum is attained. Search for 'equality in Young's inequlaity' if you cannot do this yourself.